# How do I properly encapsulate a socket.io socket?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

This code is running in my node.js server application:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    var c = new Client(socket, Tools.GenerateID());

    waitingClients.push(c);
    allClients.push(c);

    if (waitingClients.length === 2)
    {
        activeGames.push(new Game([waitingClients.pop(), waitingClients.pop()]));
    }
});

function Client(socket, id)
{
    this.Socket = socket;
    this.ID = id;
    this.Player = new Player();

    this.Update = function(supply)
    {
        socket.emit('update', { Actions: this.Player.Actions, Buys: this.Player.Buys, Coins:  this.Player.Coins, Hand: this.Player.Hand, Phase: this.Player.Phase, Supply: supply});
    }

    socket.on('play', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(this.Player);
    });

    socket.emit('id', id);
}
```

The part I'm having trouble with is the event handler for the 'play' event.  `console.log(this.Player)` outputs `undefined`.  I sorta understand why it's wrong, because 'this' refers to something other than my client object (the socket?  the anonymous function?) , but I don't know how to re-arrange the code to handle the 'play' event properly, and have full access to the members of the Client object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to store `this` in some other variable inside `Client`.

```
function Client(socket, id)
{
    var self = this;
    ...

    socket.on('play', function(data) {
        self.Player.play();
    });
```

Comment: oh my gosh how could i forget.  I've even seen a bunch of code samples with this.  thank you!